# show display a background of transparent color between text widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Need to show display a background of transparent color between these
two text widgets like the image below. tried enclosing with box decoration
property but it gives bottom overflow error. Need to highlight this text with
transparent background. Please help.
Here is code:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 120, 0, 10),
        child: Text("30 % off on first buy".tr,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            )),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0x9CFFFFFF),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 170, 0, 10),
          child: Text("Get Started Now".tr,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFADADAD),
                fontSize: 18,
              )),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image: Text]

Comment: Can you provide sample widget from scaffold body that will reproduce the same issue, More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and an image that you are trying to archive

Answer (score 1):

The Text widgets are having large padding like `170`. If you like to place widget, you can use `Stack` widget.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 10, 0, 10),
          child: Text("30 % off on first buy",
              style: const TextStyle(
                // color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0x9CFFFFFF),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 10, 0, 10),
            child: Text(
              "Get Started Now",
              style: TextStyle(
                // color: Color(0xFFADADAD),
                fontSize: 18,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Also you can use single Row with two text widget.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the rest of your code, but the second Container has more than 170 height because of your padding.

give a height value and change padding and you should be fine:

```
          Column(
            children: [
              const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 120, 0, 10),
                  child: Text("30 % off on first buy",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50, //<-added height
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0x9CFFFFFF),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),//<-changed padding to make sure text is shown
                    child: Text("Get Started Now",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```